# Javascript recursive loop to click pagination buttons on github PR

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet to expand all hidden conversations in a github PR. I found this simple bookmarklet that works for small PRs (originally from [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/781)):

```
javascript:document.querySelectorAll(".ajax-pagination-btn").forEach(l => l.click());
```

However, I frequently review large PRs that end up with threads that get buried in several levels (i.e., each click on "Load more..." exposes more pagination buttons), so I cooked up the below code to recursively expand all hidden conversations/comments, but it doesn't work beyond the first level.

```
function loadAll(level) {
    var paginationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".ajax-pagination-btn");
    console.log("loadAll found " + paginationButtons.length + " buttons in level: " + level);
    if (paginationButtons.length > 1) {
        function clickAndNext(i) {
            console.log("Processing clickAndNext for button: " + i + " in level: " + level);
            var curButton = paginationButtons[i]
            curButton.addEventListener("click", function clickAct() {
                    console.log("click for button: " + i + " in level: " + level);
                    // This shouldn't be required, since the button gets replaced, but just in case...
                    curButton.removeEventListener("click", clickAct);
                    if (i < paginationButtons.length-1) {
                        console.log("Calling clickAndNext for button: " + i + " in level: " + level);
                        clickAndNext(i+1);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Checking if level: " + (level+1) + " exists");
                        loadAll(level+1);
                    }
                })
            console.log("Clicking button: " + i + " in level: " + level);
            curButton.click();
        }
        clickAndNext(0);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No more buttons, bailing out in level: " + level);
        return;
    }
}
loadAll(0);
```

The console log looks like this:

```
VM423:3 loadAll found 7 buttons in level: 0
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 0 in level: 0
VM423:21 Clicking button: 0 in level: 0
VM423:9 click for button: 0 in level: 0
VM423:13 Calling clickAndNext for button: 0 in level: 0
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 1 in level: 0
VM423:21 Clicking button: 1 in level: 0
VM423:9 click for button: 1 in level: 0
VM423:13 Calling clickAndNext for button: 1 in level: 0
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 2 in level: 0
VM423:21 Clicking button: 2 in level: 0
VM423:9 click for button: 2 in level: 0
VM423:13 Calling clickAndNext for button: 2 in level: 0
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 3 in level: 0
VM423:21 Clicking button: 3 in level: 0
VM423:9 click for button: 3 in level: 0
VM423:13 Calling clickAndNext for button: 3 in level: 0
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 4 in level: 0
VM423:21 Clicking button: 4 in level: 0
VM423:9 click for button: 4 in level: 0
VM423:13 Calling clickAndNext for button: 4 in level: 0
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 5 in level: 0
VM423:21 Clicking button: 5 in level: 0
VM423:9 click for button: 5 in level: 0
VM423:13 Calling clickAndNext for button: 5 in level: 0
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 6 in level: 0
VM423:21 Clicking button: 6 in level: 0
VM423:9 click for button: 6 in level: 0
VM423:17 Checking if level: 1 exists
VM423:3 loadAll found 7 buttons in level: 1
VM423:6 Processing clickAndNext for button: 0 in level: 1
VM423:21 Clicking button: 0 in level: 1
```

The log indicates that the first click on the second level did nothing and so the recursion is broken.

I touch Javascript only when I am tinkering like this, so I am not too familiar with the nuances and if I am missing something obvious. Could someone help me troubleshoot?

Comment: The problem is that when you "click" the "load more" buttons, GitHub loads the content and *then* a new "load more" button appears. This is not an easy problem to fix. You probably need to use `MutationObserver`s.

Comment: @D.Pardal That is why I am calling `loadAll` recursively and the recursion breaks when there are no more pagination buttons appearing. Do you see any flaw in that approach?

Comment: Yes, the pagination buttons disappear as soon as you click them and they only appear after the data is loaded.

Comment: @D.Pardal You are right there is scope for some of them to not get expanded (especially from the very last click), but the log shows that the first time `loadAll` was called recursively, it did find 7 more buttons and initiated the first `click` as well, so why didn't that work?

Comment: Probably because those 7 buttons were already there when it started, or maybe they were created within the `click` event handler.

Comment: That is a possibility, I do see that the number of buttons in the first level was also 7, so perhaps the second query got exactly the same results which should have been outdated by then. I will try to confirm this and see if there is a way to get the query to rerun on the updated document.

Comment: You can do that with [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: I will look into `MutationObserver` too, thanks for the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217127/discussion-between-haridsv-and-d-pardal).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with my original solution was that the `click` event listener is not really an indication that the click has been fully handled (i.e., that the new page from github server has been received and that the document has already been modified). I was able to verify this fact by adding a `setTimeout` of `5s` on the recursive call to `loadAll`. However, the timeout is not only a bad workaround, it doesn't always work. It is a bad workaround because it is a constant wait time (as opposed to a callback) which significantly increases the total time it takes for the automation to complete. Also, it is not guaranteed to work unless the timeout is very large and any large number will make the entire solution pointless.

The right solution is to use a callback and thanks to @d-pardal, I was able to make use of [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to come up with the below quick solution using global variables:

```
var tgtMutationCnt = 0;
var rcvdMutationCnt = 0;
var level = 0;

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
        ++rcvdMutationCnt;
        console.log("Current mutation count: " + rcvdMutationCnt + " target mutation count: " + tgtMutationCnt + " in level: " + level);
        if (rcvdMutationCnt == tgtMutationCnt) {
            ++level;
            console.log("Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: " + level + " exists");
            loadAll();
        }
    });

function loadAll() {
    var paginationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".ajax-pagination-btn");
    console.log("loadAll found " + paginationButtons.length + " buttons in level: " + level);
    tgtMutationCnt += paginationButtons.length;
    paginationButtons.forEach(l => { 
            observer.observe(l, { childList: true, subtree: true });
            l.click();
        });
}

loadAll();
```

It would be nice to add an overlay/visual indicator to show the progress, but I am not sure how to do it right now.

I am not sure if it can be easily converted to a bookmarklet, but that is what I will look at next.

For reference, here is the output I got on the same PR that I tested before:

```
VM143:17 loadAll found 7 buttons in level: 0
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 1 target mutation count: 7 in level: 0
undefined
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 2 target mutation count: 7 in level: 0
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 3 target mutation count: 7 in level: 0
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 4 target mutation count: 7 in level: 0
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 5 target mutation count: 7 in level: 0
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 6 target mutation count: 7 in level: 0
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 7 target mutation count: 7 in level: 0
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 1 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 5 buttons in level: 1
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 8 target mutation count: 12 in level: 1
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 9 target mutation count: 12 in level: 1
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 10 target mutation count: 12 in level: 1
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 11 target mutation count: 12 in level: 1
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 12 target mutation count: 12 in level: 1
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 2 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 2 buttons in level: 2
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 13 target mutation count: 14 in level: 2
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 14 target mutation count: 14 in level: 2
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 3 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 2 buttons in level: 3
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 15 target mutation count: 16 in level: 3
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 16 target mutation count: 16 in level: 3
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 4 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 1 buttons in level: 4
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 17 target mutation count: 17 in level: 4
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 5 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 2 buttons in level: 5
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 18 target mutation count: 19 in level: 5
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 19 target mutation count: 19 in level: 5
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 6 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 1 buttons in level: 6
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 20 target mutation count: 20 in level: 6
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 7 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 2 buttons in level: 7
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 21 target mutation count: 22 in level: 7
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 22 target mutation count: 22 in level: 7
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 8 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 1 buttons in level: 8
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 23 target mutation count: 23 in level: 8
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 9 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 1 buttons in level: 9
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 24 target mutation count: 24 in level: 9
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 10 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 1 buttons in level: 10
VM143:7 Current mutation count: 25 target mutation count: 25 in level: 10
VM143:10 Target mutation count achieved, checking if level: 11 exists
VM143:17 loadAll found 0 buttons in level: 11
```

NOTE: I think I did a poor job of googling for existing solutions (or concluded too easily that this is unique to me) before I decided to reinvent the wheel, but now I find that there are many who created bookmarklets. However, all of them seem to be relying on timers that I suspect will breakdown when responses take unusually long. For references, here are a few:

- [Add way to load *all* comments when some are hidden due to number of comments](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/1892)
- [Pull request page should allow to expand all comments quickly](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1190) (this is a tampermonkey plugin)